# creating Object equality "HashMap" in ActionScript3 as java HashMap

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3

```
const jonny1 : Person = new Person("jonny", 26);
const jonny2 : Person = new Person("jonny", 26);

const table : Dictionary = new Dictionary();
table[jonny1] = "That's me";

trace(table[jonny1]) // traces: "That's me"
trace(table[jonny2]) // traces: undefined.
```

But I want use Dictionary like this way:

```
trace(table[jonny2]) // traces: "That's me".
```

in a word, I want implements a data-structure works like HashMap in java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't *believe* you can use [`Dictionary`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) in that way. From the documentation:

> The Dictionary class lets you create a dynamic collection of properties, which uses strict equality (===) for key comparison on non-primitive object keys. When an object is used as a key, the object's identity is used to look up the object, and not the value returned from calling toString() on it.

Note the references to *strict* equality, and object identity.

I don't know whether there's another data structure which *would* work, but it looks like there's nothing you can do within the objects themselves to change the behaviour of `Dictionary`, unfortunately.

You might want to look at the open source [`HashTable`](http://code.google.com/p/developmentarc-core/wiki/HashTable) project, although I can't immediately tell from the description whether that does what you want.

You might also want to look into [associative arrays](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/digitalmedia/helpcenter/actionscript30cookbook/chapter5.html?page=8).

(This is all just based on a little bit of research though - I've never actually *done* any ActionScript, so take it all with a pinch of salt.)

Answer (score 2):

A Dictionary allows for complex objects to be used as keys. As John mentioned, Dictionary cannot be used as a hashmap since it uses strict equality to check the keys of dictionary.

In contrast, an Object can be used as a map, where the keys are strings. This means that when you add a complex object as a key, that objects toString() will be invoked and used as the key in the map. In your example, you could add a toString() implementation to your Person class, which lists all of the properties that (together) make a person unique.

Consider this toString() method:

```
public function toString():String {
  return "[Person(name:" + name + ", age=" + age + ")]";
}
```

If you would then run the following test, it would pass:

```
public function testMap():void {
  var jonny1:Person = new Person("jonny", 26);
  var jonny2:Person = new Person("jonny", 26);

  var map:Object = {};
  map[jonny1] = "That's me";

  assertEquals("That's me", map[jonny2]); // succeeds
}
```

And if you would look at the map instance with a debugger, you would see:

```
map:Object
  [Person(name:jonny, age:26)] : That's me
```

Note: although this works, I'm not sure if I would recommend relying on a toString() method to check for equality. I would consider toString() to be a debugging/logging aid, which might change (and break your code).

Comment: Short of writing your own data structure, this is the only way of achieving the desired result unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a collections framework called *as3-collections* that gives you more control over object equality and object hashing. Check out https://github.com/danschultz/as3-collections for more info.